# Is there a way to send a object instead of array to the Back-End ? - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I have an table with check boxes . On click i have to collect my data in something like this :

```
"docList" : {
        "docID1" : "docNR1",
             "docID2" : "docNR2",
}
```

and after that i have to make a request to the BE . The BE will return me an ZIP file with all clicked or selected documents . Normally is pretty simple , but i have some issues .

I declare my state into the constructor :

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
         selected: []
}
};
```

And then i pass my function into the checkbox :

```
    handleCheckboxClick = (e) => {

        if(e.target.checked){
        this.setState({
            selected: [...this.state.selected, e.target.value],
        },()=>{
            console.log( this.state.selected)
        }); 
        } else {
            let remove = this.state.selected.indexOf(e.target.value);
            this.setState({
                selected: this.state.selected.filter((_, i) => i !== remove)
            },()=>{
                console.log( this.state.selected)
            }) 
        }

    }
```

```
<Checkbox value={rowData.documentId.toString() + rowData.documentNumber.toString()} onClick={this.handleCheckboxClick} />
```

And from my console i get this  :

```
["1004212942019-DGD-2000000478"]
```

Basically this is the docID + docNR combined in one string . So how can i seperate them and return an object with two seprated strings for each .

The result is not what i have expected so i will be glad if someone can give me a hand . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    docList: {}
  };
};
```

```
<Checkbox value={JSON.stringify({documentId: rowData.documentId, documentNumber: rowData.documentNumber})} onClick={this.handleCheckboxClick} />
```

```
handleCheckboxClick = (e) => {
        let parsedVal = JSON.parse(e.target.value);
        let newDocList = {...this.state.docList};
        if(e.target.checked) {
          newDocList[parsedVal.documentId] = parsedVal.documentNumber;
        } else {
          delete newDocList[parsedVal.documentId];
        }
        this.setState({
            docList: newDocList
        }, ()=>{
            console.log(this.state.docList)
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: rowData = by this way i extract the whole value of the document . The thing is that i want only the documentNr and the documentId . Thats why i have target it inside of the checkbox's value like :  `rowData.documentId` .

Comment: @PandaMastr I've just edited the answer. Please let me know if that is was you intended.

Comment: almost there . `0: {documentId: 100421294, documentNumber: "2019-BRS-2000000478"}` . Now i think i have to map thru them to recieve this structure `docList : {
  "docId1" : "docNr1",
  "docId2" : "docNr2"
}`

Comment: @PandaMastr I've made one last edit. Please let me know if it works. It wasn't clear from your question because you used an array in the state. I had to change everything.

Comment: Indeed this is the answer that i have looked for . Cheers mate ! Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attributes - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

```
<Checkbox data-docId={rowData.documentId.toString()} data-docNumber={rowData.documentNumber.toString()} onClick={this.handleCheckboxClick} />
```

Inside `handleCheckboxClick` you can get the `data` values in the event object.